# Using realworld body sensor data for model animation

Tags: animation, rigging

Characters in movies are sometimes animated by using the movements of an actor who wears several sensors on her body which record the movements (e.g. "Gollum" in Lord of the Rings).

How can any type of sensor data be applied to animate models with "real" movements?

(Now, I've to admit I'm so unaccustomed to Blender that I do not even know what to search for to get decent help / docs / tutorials.)

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=blender+motion+capture+tools =)

Comment: Motion capture! Oh, my :) Could have thought on that one myself. Well, I could have if I would have ;-) Thx a lot!